# How to perform Tukey HSD test in Spark Dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, statistics, tukey

I am trying to perform the Tukey's test on a very large dataset using pyspark.
Now I know in python we can use the `pairwise_tukeyhsd` library from the `statsmodels.stats.multicomp` module.
That would require me to convert my spark data frame to pandas data frame which defeats the purpose of using RDD and will not work on my large dataset.

The other way is to manually do the test mathematically on the spark dataframes which is simple enough as shown [here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/tukey-test-honest-significant-difference/)
However, to compare the `means` with the `Q_crit` value, I would need Tukey's critical value table.

Is there any way to calculate the critical values on the Tukey table?